# Max and min time checks in case statement using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time, switch-statement, max, min

I what to check a time with a case statement. How to do?

Comment: Your question isn't terribly clear. You might want to include more information...

Comment: Sorry for my "stupid" question, but it is the RoR mania that make me crazy! :-)

Comment: @user502052: The problem isn't that it's about a basic topic. The problem is that you don't clearly describe what you want.

Comment: I agree that the question should be more specific in what it is looking for.  Possibly including an example situation (e.g. I have a date `date = Time.now` and I want to know if it is between `1.days.ago` and `1.weeks.ago` by a case statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the version that doesn't have a defined variable at the top...

```
t = event.time  # arbitrary example.

case
when t <= Time.now
  # Event is in the past.
else
  # Event is in the future.
end
```

Comment: But see, I really don't see any advantage to doing this over a simple if else statement... I agree with the comment the question is not very clear.

Comment: @Nikhil, you're quite right. this example is pretty stupid :). hopefully the OP can generalize though, if they have more complicated requirements.

Comment: Sorry for my "stupid" question, but it is the RoR mania that make me crazy! :-)

Comment: @user502052: nope, I didn't mean your question was stupid, I meant my example in my answer was stupid :)

Comment: This is just a bastardized `if` statement, I don't get how this can be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use ranges:

```
case time
when (Time.now - 60)..(Time.now) then puts 'within the last minute'
when (Time.now - 3600)..(Time.now) then puts 'within the last hour'
end
```

Ranges work with all sorts of values. You can use `Date`s too:

```
case date
when (Date.today - 1)..(Date.today) then puts 'less than a day ago'
when (Date.today - 30)..(Date.today) then puts 'less than a month ago'
end
```

Update: Ruby 1.9 broke Time ranges, so that example works only in Ruby 1.8.7. The Date example works in both versions though. In 1.9 you can use this code to match a Time:

```
case time.to_i
when ((Time.now - 60).to_i)..(Time.now.to_i) then puts 'within the last minute'
when ((Time.now - 3600).to_i)..(Time.now.to_i) then puts 'within the last hour'
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work - you can't use ranges with `Time` in a case statement due to lack of support for `===`... tried testing it and it doesn't work.

Comment: The code works fine in Ruby 1.8.7, but you're right, seems like 1.9 breaks it. The example with Date works in both, though.